# Null values Return wrong value in TAdsQuery and works properly with TFDQuery. in Delphi Tokyo

Tags: delphi, advantage-database-server

If I run any SQL statement that should return a Null value from Advantage Database Server it would return the value of -922337203685477.58 instead of null.

However, this only happens if I use the native TAdsQuery from Advantage if I use TFDQuery from fireDac all is ok

```
SQL: Select Cast(Null AS SQL_MONEY) Value From System.iota;
```

The Same example works properly in XE7 but not in Tokyo, 
TDataSet installation was done according to instruction on https://www.jd-engineering.de/ads-and-delphi-10-2-tokyo/.

Comment: Is this a bug report? Perhaps you should submit it to the related party.

Comment: It may well be a setting or some workaround I'm missing. In each case, there is no updates for ADS coming anytime soon and no real support, so some workaround or modification to TAdsQuery would be needed

Comment: Which version of ADS is this from? Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Ver 12. the answer works! My vote is just not showing yet.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug, Joachim found it and posted a fix for it:

https://www.jd-engineering.de/advantage-returning-wrong-value-on-null-in-delphi-tokyo/

> I was reported that the Advantage Delphi client doesn’t return NULL on
>   MONEY data type in Delphi Tokyo. After some research, I’ve found a bug
>   in adsdata.pas: Line 5996 compares the data buffer with the value that
>   represents NULL in ADS. It casts the content to a Signed64 for the
>   comparison:
>
> ```
> if ( pSIGNED64 ( pcData )^ <> $8000000000000000 ) then
> ```
>
> All other comparisons in that function (TAdsDataSet.IsFieldBlank)
>   compare to Unsigned values instead. So modifying the above line with
>
> ```
> if ( PUNSIGNED64 ( pcData )^ <> $8000000000000000 ) then
> ```
>
> fixes the issue.